# CreateStyleForwardersForDefaultStyles missing in version 5

Tags: catel

I have some old libraries coded in .net 4.0 using an old version of Catel (3.9). Now I'm trying to upgrade to .net 4.7.2 using the latest Catel. I've added Orc.Controls instead of Catel.Extensions.Controls, but CreateStyleForwardersForDefaultStyles and StyleHelper are missing.
Do I need to adjust all of my xaml files manually or there is some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StyleHelper and other style related code has been moved to Orc.Theming and Orchestra.

The example apps for both libraries (should) show how to use them.